# Chrome Extension JavaScript — Grabbing content from external site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I would like to grab some values from a website’s table to make use of in my extension. This external site though is generated mainly from JavaScript which creates for example the HTML table on the fly. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Use a content script and dynamically scrap the content

Comment: But would that not require the user to visit the webpage in the browser? I’d like to do this in the background?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using "content script" Please refer this document in details
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: But would I need to use an iFrame in the background page if I can’t expect the user to visit the webpage themselves or open a new tab with the webpage?